# date format issues after updating iPad version 8.3

Tags: ios, ipad

date format issues after updating iPad version 8.3 below code return NIL value but works  fine in simulator and iPod

```
-(NSString *)dateFormat:(NSString *)str{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];      
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

 //problem here when i call this method from simulator and ipod it runs  perfectly
 //and returns  2015-01-27 00:27:48 +0000 but in case of IPad(iOS 8.3) it return NIL

NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString* myString = [df stringFromDate:dateFromString];
return myString;
}

//code to call above method with date string which are return from web service
[self dateFormat:@"2015/01/26 16:27:48 PST"];
```

Comment: This code works  fine in iPad Air and iPAD 2 running on iOS 8.3. Seems no problem.

Comment: dateFromString returns NIL on iPAD running on iOS 8.3  @Vizllx

Comment: months should be MM instead of mm

Answer (score 1):

Check the input string date format. 
 It should be in this format: -  `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzz`

Comment: [self dateFormat:@"2015/01/26 16:27:48 PST"];

Comment: Use his, this working for me on iPhone 8.3`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zz"];`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the ipad Date and Time Settings. To convert the string, 2015/01/26 16:27:48 PST into date, the ipad date and time format must be 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Month is represented by 'MM' and not 'mm'. Change the date format as

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```